# Best way to discard data from a pipe or socket in linux?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I've got a situation where I might want to "skip" data in a pipe or socket for processing.  I could of course read() the data into a buffer and just discard it, but is there a more efficient way?  Perhaps something like sendfile that would work with a non-mmappable source?

Comment: Can’t you just redirect to /dev/null?

Comment: How can I do that with a socket? Bearing in mind all I have is an int file descriptor.

Comment: Maybe using [splice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) or tee(2) ? `int nullfd = open(/dev/null, O_W); while(splice(fd, NULL, nullfd, NULL, (S?)SIZE_MAX, SPLICE_F_NONBLOCK) > 0);`

Comment: I recommend posting what code you have tried (and timed) and ask for speedily approaches to the higher level goal: **speed**. The question so far is "Best way to discard data" is only 1 way to do this.  Better to ask how to achieve the higher/true goal.

Answer (score 5):

You need to `read` the data. What you do with it is up to you, so you can skip over parts, or whatever.

Without reading it the data stays stuck in the read buffer. The recommended way to get it out of the buffer is to read it.

That being said, if you read something that indicates that all subsequent data will be of no use, you could just close the connection and be done with it.

I'm not sure what you mean about "efficient" because reading from a buffer is probably not the performance bottleneck in your code.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to copy into the user buffer since I'll just ignore it.  We do a _lot_ of high throughput streaming so we do actually run into memory bandwidth issues.

Comment: It's not clear if this is kernel code or not, and it's also not clear what kind of access patterns you're trying to implement. Just how much data are you handling that memory bandwidth starts to be a constraint? Usually it's hard to saturate that without running out of network bandwidth first.

Comment: Remember in the kernel the memory access costs are far lower, so if you are really up against the wall you can implement part of your code as a loadable kernel module. The cost of IO there is significantly lower since there's no need to copy to userspace. You can manipulate network buffers directly.

Comment: If memory bandwidth is an issue, are you sure you should be using pipes?

Comment: @tadman This is not kernel code.  Part of the problem is that our working set sizes are frequently larger than L3 cache, so any pressure we put on the memory bus doing unnecessary copies really hurts latency.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister: Both pipes and sockets have relatively small capacities — 64 KiB for pipes on Linux, probably less for a socket.  Reading into a 64 KiB buffer is unlikely to put much pressure on an L3 cache on modern workstation or server hardware.

Comment: @SeanMcAllister, it sounds like you are trying to forecast performance impact.  That can be an amusing exercise, but it is notoriously difficult to do accurately.  And in this case, it really doesn't matter, because for non-seekable files such as sockets and pipes, you have no alternative to reading the data in order to advance through the stream, and no userspace interface for reading the data without putting it somewhere.

Comment: @JohnBollinger At least with pipes, I can splice() to /dev/null and TCP sockets support MSG_TRUNC to discard data, but it does indeed look like there's no general purpose answer.

Comment: There's probably a way to solve this that doesn't involve dark hackery, but without knowing more about your specific goals I can't really advise. If you want to ignore past a certain point, you have several options. If you need to skip ahead an arbitrary number of bytes that's a different problem. If this is network based I'm not sure how you'd be exhausting memory bandwidth when that should be around 40GB/s vs. ~0.250-1.25GB/s for your network connection. There should be considerable headroom here, even when accounting for user-mode costs.

Comment: If you need to burn through a lot of data, experiment with different buffer block sizes and see which one comes out on top performance-wise. If you had some example code that demonstrated what you were trying to do that would help considerably as we could benchmark too.

Comment: Well OK, @SeanMcAllister, since you did ask specifically about Linux.  Both `splice()` and `MSG_TRUNC` are in fact Linux-specific.